# Returning a title cased list and removing duplicates

Tags: python, list

I'm new to programming, and I picked Python to start learning first because there was a sale on some resources for learning it on Humble Bundle. That put me on the PyBites website, where I'm doing a programming exercise to manipulate a list. Here is the code I am having trouble with.

```
NAMES = ['arnold schwarzenegger', 'alec baldwin', 'bob belderbos',
         'julian sequeira', 'sandra bullock', 'keanu reeves',
         'julbob pybites', 'bob belderbos', 'julian sequeira',
         'al pacino', 'brad pitt', 'matt damon', 'brad pitt']
import re

def dedup_and_title_case_names(names):
    """Should return a list of title cased names,
       each name appears only once"""
    name_list = []
    name_set = set()
    for name in names:
        if name in name_set == set(names):
            pass
        else:
            name_set.add(name)
            name_list.append(name.title())
    return name_list
```

So PyBites does a check to determine if your code is working. In the check, I have one pass and six failures (because I've been stuck on this third of the exercise), I believe, based on running this in PyCharm, that it's keeping the first duplicate that shows up (bob belderbos), but it does not keep the second duplicate (brad pitt).

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you want to combine `==` with `in` in a single statement? Note that `name in name_set == set(names)` is just like `(name in name_set) and (name_set == set(names))`. (You can refer to https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons ) . If you change the if statement to `if name in name_set:` , do you get what you want?

Comment: I have no clue why my code was doing what it was doing, but I guess that's what you get when you've only been programming a few days... But your comment worked, thank you @qrsngky !

Comment: But then it's not entirely correct if you have an example like `NAMES = ['brad Pitt', 'brad pItt']`. It creates two different entries in `name_set`, even though the result of `name.title()` is the same, and you get duplicates in the final output. One way is to make a set that collects `name.title()`, instead of one that collects `name`. There are more convenient syntaxes, though, for example, as shown in someone else's answer below (be careful about indentations, though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
def dedup_and_title_case_names(names):
    """Should return a list of title cased names,
       each name appears only once"""
   
    return list(set([name.title() for name in names]))
```